# add filter query in Google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am having problem with filtering the entities after addFilter() has been

deprecated from Google App Engine .

Objective : to list those Entities which are having UID = "rahul"

what i tried :

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService ds=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Query q = new Query("Upload");
    q.setFilter(FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("UID","rahul"));
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);

    for (Entity result : pq.asIterable())   

       {
            String title = (String) result.getProperty("url");
            resp.getWriter().println(title);
        }
```

And this is my DataStore Instance for "Upload" Entity :

[image: Upload Entity Instance in Datastore]

But, I am getting a blank page when launching the app .

Comment: @frank that JAVA was not a TAG but a Clear distinction . that this Google app Engine question is based on JAVA version . NOT the Python .

Comment: yeah .. there was a typo with Datastore name.

Comment: This was helpful but I have an issue to compare to specific number, I have a number stored and I'm trying to filter by this specific number using "equal" , but it shows me that there is nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should give the desired output. If it is giving blank page then kindly check logs in Google Dashboard or shared logs.

Answer (score 2):

As `addFilter()` is deprecated, you may also use following code:

**To create a single filter:**

```
query.setFilter(new Query.FilterPredicate("UID", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "rahul"));
```

**To create multiple filters:**

After you build all of your filters, combine them together using a CompositeFilter:

```
new CompositeFilter(CompositeFilterOperator.AND, Arrays.asList(filter1, filter2));
```

Then set it as the filter to your query by writing:

```
query.setFilter(composite_filter);
```